# keep running a cell in jupyter notebook remotely after shutting down the local machine

Tags: python, pandas, server, jupyter-notebook

I am working with my local machine and running my algorithms in a server. In order to keep the Jupyter notebook running, I run this command in the server:

> nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser &

I access to the jupyter notebook server in my local machine through this cmd:

```
ssh -nNT -L 9999:localhost:8888 myuser@ipServer
```

I was trying to run this both coding lines in a cell in jupyter:

```
profile=pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_file(outputfile='myoutputfile_FINAL_DATASET.html')
```

The dataset is huge: 4,51 GB with 840.000 rows and 5308 columns (It took 4 days to run that)

I thought that if I added these two lines running with nohup it will keep the variable profile, and going to the line below. However, it seems the variable profile just went away after it finish running the first line.

Is there anyway to run the whole cell when closing jupyter notebook in your local machine?

EDIT:

I realized that something happened this morning, and suddenly, the kernel restarted for no reason at **[I 06:54:03.346 NotebookApp]**

```
[I 12:43:53.577 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for c9688f9f-ed12-4eff-a18c-aa300b62faf1:8a1a4286bc5d43d6823c15c9ad8c9512
[I 12:43:55.592 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for b207c9f7-f0c7-40e7-8f67-1c85024a8be6:4a9971a622294cd1832873e0fbc181f0
[I 06:54:03.346 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
[I 09:35:34.509 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (127.0.0.1) 24.76ms
[W 09:35:35.347 NotebookApp] 404 GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png (127.0.0.1) 53.83ms referer=None
[W 09:35:35.376 NotebookApp] 404 GET /apple-touch-icon.png (127.0.0.1) 1.23ms referer=None
[I 09:35:47.593 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel b207c9f7-f0c7-40e7-8f67-1c85024a8be6
[I 09:37:47.424 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Profiling_FINAL_DATASET.ipynb
[I 09:39:49.759 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Profiling_FINAL_DATASET.ipynb
[I 09:41:49.777 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Profiling_FINAL_DATASET.ipynb
[W 09:44:47.657 NotebookApp] WebSocket ping timeout after 119897 ms.
[I 09:44:52.708 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for b207c9f7-f0c7-40e7-8f67-1c85024a8be6:eb4a6d0415604f078b9c0229d93cdc33
[I 10:04:17.875 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel b207c9f7-f0c7-40e7-8f67-1c85024a8be6
[I 10:04:17.884 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for b207c9f7-f0c7-40e7-8f67-1c85024a8be6:eb4a6d0415604f078b9c0229d93cdc33
[I 10:04:25.803 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (127.0.0.1) 3.45ms
[I 10:04:42.583 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel b207c9f7-f0c7-40e7-8f67-1c85024a8be6
[I 10:07:56.233 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Profiling_FINAL_DATASET.ipynb
[I 10:09:56.421 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Profiling_FINAL_DATASET.ipynb
```

Comment: What do you mean it "went away"? Please explain what behavior you saw. And I think you need to give more details about how you interface with the server.

Comment: @alexis see edit. I meant, that the file myoutputfile_FINAL_DATASET.html is not created, meaning that the second line did not execute